# Is there a definite list of MIME types?

Tags: mime-types, mime

I understand that you can configure servers to associate a specific extension with a particular MIME type. Who defines those MIME types? Can I create my own custom type (like xyz/dfds) and if so, what's the point of it? Say I decide to do so, how will I tell browsers like Chrome etc how to interpret it?

Comment: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

The *authoritative* list of MIME types is the IANA Media Types registry at http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml but it is by no means *exhaustive.*

Like you surmise, there are valid reasons for implementors to use unofficial types which are not part of the registry, for a number of reasons, including, but not limited to

- limited private use
- specialized needs not adequately addressed by IANA
- opposition to, or alternatives to, IANA-specified standard types
- testing or preparation for official IANA standardization

A grandiose example is the plethora of different MIME type identifiers applied to the PKzip archive format; you see `application/zip`,  `application/x-zip-compressed`, and just plain `application/octet-stream`, among the more popular ones.

For your specific question about browser support for ad-hoc types, a common approach is to create a plug-in for the browser(s) you want to support.  Do note that MIME is not limited to the WWW; it originated with email, and has uses in many other applications as well.